# Best Thin Client Setup

Tags: linux, windows, local-area-network, thin-client, server-setup

I'm new here and I'm looking for information for a personal question I have since the beginning of the year.

This year I had my first contact with a workspace that uses thin clients, but it's all in the cloud with no local resources. I was wondering if at some point they were without internet what would they do? Since then I have been imagining and I did some research that were not very well answered regarding a possible setup where they would have a local server as a redundancy backup when there is a lack of internet.

Would you like to discuss with more experienced people here what would be the best option for this setup?

Which of these ideas I formed would have the most advantage? (performance, cost, configuration, maintenance)

Idea 1:
Local server with all users (let's assume 10 max) connecting simultaneously on the same OS.

Idea 2:
Local server with type 1 hypervisor (esxi, proxmox...) virtualizing an OS for each user.

Idea 3:
Local server with type 2 hypervisor (VMware, qemu...) on an OS Host virtualizing an OS for each user.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2b4T.jpg)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to go for option 4: invest in redundant Internet connection and forget about an idea of deploying on-premises solution in 2021 (unless there is a specific need for one, of course).

To recover from those rare occasions your office looses Internet, it can cost as low as an additional router with a SIM card in it.

The reality nowadays is, a cost to support redundant on-premises solution would be much higher, would actually increase downtime risks and would bring no real business benefit.